# Is it possible to disable a button in angular js when there are any custom ng-message errors present in the form?

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages, angularjs-ng-disabled

Is is possible to disable a button in a form, when there is any error message in the form other than built in errors such as 'required', 'min-length', such as validating a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following helps

1. If you are setting custom errors using `$scope.formName.$setValidity('errName', false);`, then you can use `formName.$error.errName` as a condition in ng-disabled

In JS,

```
$scope.formName.$setValidity('errName', false);//invalidate the form
```

You can set the error to true when needed.

In HTML,

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="formName.$error.err">Button</button>
```

2. You can use a flag and toggle it to true when error and use that flag in ng-disabled

In JS,

```
$scope.disableBtn = true; //whenever button is to be disabled.
```

In HTML,

`<button type="button" ng-disabled="disableBtn">Button</button>`

UPDATE: Adding plunker link
https://plnkr.co/edit/5CFpFMAnZ8kkBh5z5vH4?p=preview